# leaflet tilelayer from localhost geoserver

Tags: geoserver, leaflet

I am attempting to construct a tilelayer link from a local geoserver. the layer is called county and I seem to have set it up correctly to be called as a tilelayer

[image]

now as I am following the leaflet documentation http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#tilelayer

I am getting confused on how to construct the URL

here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map{ height: 100% }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>

  // initialize the map
  var map = L.map('map').setView([40.876,-74.9999], 13);

  // base maps
  var county=L.tileLayer('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pg_world:county/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

nothing shows up when I display this in google chrome.

in the console I get this error

[image]

how do I properly construct this tilelayer URL?

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet assumes that you are providing a template to either a TMS or WMTS REST endpoint. GeoServer doesn't provide a WMTS REST endpoint only KVP so you need to provide a template that matches the TMS endpoint. To find out what yours is download the TMS capabilities document from your home page. You should see a URL like:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/topp%3Astates@EPSG%3A4326@png

Which you can modify to be a template by adding `/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` to the end of.

Comment: so I found http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/pg_world%3Acounty@EPSG%3A4326@png but it wont display. even after I add /{z}/{x}/{y}.png

Comment: still cannot figure out the syntax here

Comment: can you request tiles in the browser bar by adding /0/0/0.png ? if not then you have broken your layer else you have a leaflet issue